# Parsing JSON row by row documents

Tags: r, json

I am trying to parse a json file into a dataframe which I think it requires to be read line by line and appended (rbind).

Each single line contains info similar to this

Sample file
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am7buNMZi-gwgdkSeGxFZms94DhfhQ?e=XdAJhg

I would like to get a a df with columns
period,frameIdx, gameClock,live,lasttouch, type_object(homeplayer,awayplayer, ball) and xyz

Each row contains info similar to this

```
{
"period": 1, 
"frameIdx": 0, 
"gameClock": 0.0, 
"homePlayers": [{"playerId": "872", "xyz": [-8.92, -27.61, 0.0], "speed": 0.51}, 
                {"playerId": "251", "xyz": [-14.71, 0.39, 0.0], "speed": 0.62}, 
                {"playerId": "917", "xyz": [-17.76, -14.85, 0.0], "speed": 0.63}, 
                {"playerId": "41320", "xyz": [-4.65, 7.18, 0.0], "speed": 0.87}, 
                {"playerId": "90105", "xyz": [0.58, -0.22, 0.0], "speed": 0.6}, 
                {"playerId": "40387", "xyz": [-1.3, -9.15, 0.0], "speed": 0.94}, 
                {"playerId": "40349", "xyz": [-42.49, -0.52, 0.0], "speed": 0.78}, 
                {"playerId": "111317", "xyz": [0.14, -13.02, 0.0], "speed": 2.38}, 
                {"playerId": "78007", "xyz": [0.58, -32.0, 0.0], "speed": 3.53}, 
                {"playerId": "75115", "xyz": [0.92, -25.82, 0.0], "speed": 4.4}, 
                {"playerId": "126184", "xyz": [-20.59, -4.18, 0.0], "speed": 0.85}], 

"awayPlayers": [{"playerId": "54484", "xyz": [20.95, 7.7, 0.0], "speed": 0.16}, 
                {"playerId": "989", "xyz": [51.21, -0.98, 0.0], "speed": 1.3}, 
                {"playerId": "145", "xyz": [22.0, -6.32, 0.0], "speed": 0.41}, 
                {"playerId": "41338", "xyz": [20.34, -15.46, 0.0], "speed": 0.31}, 
                {"playerId": "868", "xyz": [19.73, -27.08, 0.0], "speed": 0.81}, 
                {"playerId": "1725", "xyz": [-0.35, -8.3, 0.0], "speed": 2.18}, 
                {"playerId": "924", "xyz": [-0.17, 8.53, 0.0], "speed": 4.26}, 
                {"playerId": "7775", "xyz": [10.13, 11.29, 0.0], "speed": 0.97}, 
                {"playerId": "38439", "xyz": [13.64, -13.93, 0.0], "speed": 0.54}, 
                {"playerId": "61566", "xyz": [7.85, -22.77, 0.0], "speed": 0.52}, 
                {"playerId": "599", "xyz": [16.38, -6.32, 0.0], "speed": 0.0}], 

"ball": {"xyz": [-0.08, 0.17, 0.0], "speed": 12.57}, 
"live": false,
"lastTouch": "home"
}
```

Ideally resultant df will have this format in columns after gather cols to rows

```
**period,frameIdx,gameClock,type_object,playerId,xyz,speed,live,lastTouch**

1,0,0.0, homePlayer, 872,[-8.92, -27.61, 0.0], 0.0,false, home

1,0,0.0, homePlayer, 251,[-15.92, -22.61, 0.0], 0.0,false, home

...
1,0,0.0, homePlayer, 126184,[-20.59, -4.18, 0.0], 0.0,false, home

1,0,0.0, awayPlayer, 54484,[20.95, 7.7, 0.0]   ,0.0, false, home

...
1,0,0.0, awayPlayer, 599,[20.95, 7.7, 0.0]   , 0.0,false, home


1,0,0.0, ball,  ,[-0.08, 0.17, 0.0]   ,12.57, false, home
```

23 rows in df for each row in json file

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)      # for %>% and other dplyr functions
library(rjson)

# tried several options to read file in a single option with no luck

file_match_json <- 'match.jsonl'

json.text <- readLines(file_match_json)
json      <- lapply(json.text,fromJSON)


result <- do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(json,as.data.frame,optional=T))

result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening a connection with `jsonlite::stream_in` as such:

```
result <- as_tibble(stream_in(file(file_match_json)))

> result
# A tibble: 30 x 8
   period frameIdx gameClock homePlayers       awayPlayers       ball$xyz  $speed live  lastTouch
    <int>    <int>     <dbl> <list>            <list>            <list>     <dbl> <lgl> <chr>    
 1      1        0      0    <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.6 FALSE home     
 2      1        1      0.04 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.8 TRUE  home     
 3      1        2      0.08 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.8 TRUE  home     
 4      1        3      0.12 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.8 TRUE  home     
 5      1        4      0.16 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.7 TRUE  home     
 6      1        5      0.2  <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.5 TRUE  home     
 7      1        6      0.24 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.3 TRUE  home     
 8      1        7      0.28 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   12.0 TRUE  home     
 9      1        8      0.32 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   11.8 TRUE  home     
10      1        9      0.36 <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <dbl [3]>   11.5 TRUE  home     
# … with 20 more rows
```

You will then have to `unnest()` the nested dataframes.

Since I am not very well-versed on `nest`/`unnest` and `purrr` functions, my solution is a workaround - I'd also like to see how to proper address this. I am creating two different unnested dataframes and then binding them together:

```
t <- result %>% unnest(homePlayers, .preserve = awayPlayers) %>% mutate(who='homePlayers') %>% select(-awayPlayers)
t2 <- result %>% unnest(awayPlayers, .preserve = homePlayers) %>% mutate(who='awayPlayers') %>% select(-homePlayers)
new_result <- bind_rows(t,t2) # this is your final result
```

> You might run into the problem that there are different NAs inside your dataframes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36816426/7856717) post, or [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-unnest-columns-with-different-number-of-elements/9576) one for solutions regarding this problem.

Comment: NAs on my data?  not seeing them...only for id type in ball rows

Comment: I didn't check them for NAs myself - when i tried `unnest()` i did get the Error `# Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.` which is commonly occurring due to NAs, hence my suggestion.

Comment: yes friend having same issue, thanks for your support

Comment: Edited my response with `unnest` for your homePlayers and awayPlayers tables.

Comment: df <- df %>% unnest(homePlayers, awayPlayers)                                                                              this option is perfect but I need an extra column with home/away

Comment: Take a look at the new update. I am essentially creating two new dataframes (one for each unnest) and then binding them together. It is certainly **not** the optimal solution, but is it what you've been looking for?

Comment: Also you might find these [1](https://cfss.uchicago.edu/notes/simplify-nested-lists/), [2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-nested-json-to-a-tidy-data-frame-with-r/) links useful, to either re-parse your JSON file better or add the missing ball xyz/speed details. Best of luck!

Comment: I am stuck getting ball info in rows to append                                                                    b <-result %>%
   select(period,frameIdx,gameClock,live,lastTouch,ball$xyz, ball$speed)%>% 
   mutate(who='ball',playerId=-1) 
   
final <- bind_rows(t,t2,b)